# FFMPEG, can't stream rtmp static image with mp3

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, rtmp

I try to stream on my own rtmp nginx server an single static jpeg image with an mp3 which have about an hour, and from my nginx rtmp to YouTube, but audio is not constant and without image...
This is what I used...

```
#! /bin/bash
 
VBR="1500k"
FPS="30"
QUAL="ultrafast"
YOUTUBE_URL="rtmp://localhost:1935/live"
YOUTUBE_KEY="test"
VIDEO_SOURCE="image.jpg"
AUDIO_SOURCE="music.mp3"
AUDIO_ENCODER="libmp3lame"
 
ffmpeg \
 -loop 1 \
 -re \
 -framerate $FPS \
 -i "$VIDEO_SOURCE" \
 -thread_queue_size 512 \
 -i "$AUDIO_SOURCE" \
 -c:v libx264 -preset $QUAL -r $FPS -g $(($FPS *2)) -b:v $VBR \
 -c:a $AUDIO_ENCODER -threads "$(nproc)" -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -bufsize 512k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
 -vf scale=1280x720,setsar=1:1 \
 -f flv $YOUTUBE_URL/$YOUTUBE_KEY
```

Output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, image2, from 'unsplash.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1976946 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 7952x4472 [SAR 72:72 DAR 994:559], 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
Input #1, mp3, from 'ArtOfTrippyCode.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 01:07:25.34, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 141 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 141 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (mp3 (mp3float) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x564a7bd3ed80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] VBV maxrate unspecified, assuming CBR
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=2 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=60 keyint_min=6 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=0 rc=cbr mbtree=0 bitrate=1500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 vbv_maxrate=1500 vbv_bufsize=512 nal_hrd=none filler=0 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://localhost:1935/live/test':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 1500 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1500000 buffer size: 512000 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libmp3lame
[flv @ 0x564a7b3e8340] Failed to update header with correct duration.863.7kbits/s speed=0.0424x
[flv @ 0x564a7b3e8340] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=   15 fps=1.6 q=-1.0 Lsize=      97kB time=00:00:00.47 bitrate=1686.4kbits/s speed=0.0511x
video:88kB audio:8kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.021540%
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] frame I:1     Avg QP:34.00  size: 25690
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] frame P:14    Avg QP:29.21  size:  4569
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] mb P  I16..4:  0.5%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 16.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:83.5%
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 51.0% 11.4% 1.2% inter: 8.2% 3.3% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] i16 v,h,dc,p: 32% 25% 31% 13%
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] i8c dc,h,v,p: 82% 11%  7%  0%
[libx264 @ 0x564a7b3e9680] kb/s:1434.54
```

Comment: Console output shows `fps=1.6`. Should be 30. Need to find out the bottleneck. Try outputting to a local file to test: replace `-f flv $YOUTUBE_URL/$YOUTUBE_KEY` with `output.flv`.

Comment: @llogan I have the same issue. fps goes down from 2 to 0 when time increases.